# how to use primefaces growl for notifications without any event on page?

Tags: primefaces, notifications, growl

I would like to show a message to user when some conditions occur within my application. how can i do this aside from user interaction on pages?

Comment: You can use primefaces poll available at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf and update growl on it's ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

See the primepush chat example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf;jsessionid=9tv0tk0u9g1xq7oxguewdg6t) and see the usage of growl.